# How to get first EntityKey Name for an Entity in EF4

Tags: entity-framework, repository, entity, entity-framework-4, entitykey

How can I get the 1st EntityKey name for an Entity for Entity Framework 4 because I'm building a repository system and I wanted to get an item by Id (which is the primary key oin EF is the 1st entitykey for the entity)

I'm using this code

```
public virtual TEntity GetById(string keyName, Guid entityId)
        {
            var entityKey = new EntityKey(this.QualifiedEntitySetName, keyName, entityId);
            object entity;
            return this.Context.TryGetObjectByKey(entityKey, out entity) ? entity as TEntity : null;
        }
```

I want to get the entity key name dynamic.
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

var keyName = this.Context
        .MetadataWorkspace
        .GetEntityContainer(this.Context.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace)
        .BaseEntitySets
        .First(meta => meta.ElementType.Name == this.entityName)
        .ElementType
        .KeyMembers
        .Select(k => k.Name)
        .FirstOrDefault();

I know it looks too much but u I wanted to get it by having the Entity Name.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Entity Key members collection from MetaDataWorkspace using the following code:

```
ReadOnlyCollection keyMembers = db.MetadataWorkspace.GetType("", "Entity_Namespace", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.DataSpace.CSpace).MetadataProperties["KeyMembers"].Value as ReadOnlyCollection;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the entity key for the POCO Entity type.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="entity">The entity.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private EntityKey GetEntityKey(TEntity entity)
{
    ReadOnlyMetadataCollection<EdmMember> keyMembers =
        this.ObjectSet.EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers;

    var entityKeyMembers = new List<EntityKeyMember>();

    //Construct the entity key for the POCO Entity type object.
    foreach (EdmMember keyMember in keyMembers)
    {
        object keyMemberValue = entity.GetType().GetProperty(keyMember.Name).GetValue(entity, null);
        entityKeyMembers.Add(new EntityKeyMember(keyMember.Name, keyMemberValue));
    }

    //Create the Entity key for our POCO Entity type object.
    return new EntityKey(this.ObjectSource.DefaultContainerName
        + "." + this.ObjectSet.EntitySet.Name, entityKeyMembers);
}
```

objectsource is objectcontext.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetPrimaryKeyName(this object entity)
   {
       var prop = entity.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x =>x.GetCustomAttributes(false).Where(y => y is ColumnAttribute&&((ColumnAttribute)y).IsPrimaryKey == true).Any()).FirstOrDefault();
          if (prop != null)
              return prop.Name;
          return string.Empty;

   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I didn't tried it but the question is already answered four years ago :)