# How to compare POCO class with Database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, smo, roslyn

I need to compare what's on my `POCO` classes against my database.
I am currently using `Microsoft Roslyn` and `Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO` and comparing the data, in my opinion, 'roughly'. It's working perfectly, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do so.

Today I have to compile the file using Roslyn, load the database info and compare what I want.

Let's say I have this `POCO` file:

```
[Table("XPTO", Schema="ASD")]
public class MyPoco 
{
    public int PropId {get; set;}
    public virtual Prop Prop {get; set;}
    public DateTime? MyDate {get; set;}
}
```

And I also have the Table info. I want to see if what is nullable in my `POCO` class (MyDate) is nullable on my database and vice-versa. I want to see if my database has a `Foreign Key` to table `Props` and if it is not-nullable as in my `POCO`.

As I said, it's already working today, I just wanted to rewrite the code to use a more effective way to even maintain.

Does EntityFramework provide some sort of API or anything?

**System Info**

```
SQL Server 2008 R2
Entity Framework 4.1
C# 4.0
```

Thanks();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your question right - you'd want some API to fetch the `relationshiops` and other `metadata` information from the `DbContext` or EF/code-first at runtime?

The best I've seen so far - and the best the two of us could do was this...

[How I can read EF DbContext metadata programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718301/how-i-can-read-ef-dbcontext-metadata-programmatically/15720297#15720297)

...take a look if this can help you...

> And you're welcome to post there if you happen to come into possession
>   of some new and vital piece of information (we made it with the intention to serve as a
>   one-stop question for subjects like this).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that could be a place to start. That is basically what I need, except that I need to fetch the differences between the instantiated context, or even the POCO files themselves, as I can use Roslyn for that, and compare with the DB. I'll take a look at your answer and see if that works for me. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, this is the current 'runtime' snapshot - those should 'correspond' to the Db. But for a 'real Db' state - you'd need to query the Db - use the system table to fetch tables, relationships, fields etc. and build your `Left` model (Db) - then compare to the `Right` model (your code one). That's what I used a bit simplified with Db code generators, you go hierarchically and compare, something like that at least:)

Comment: I just took a deeper look into your approach, but seeing that you instantiate the context I decided not to go that way. The problem is that I check the poco files and using the attributes I compare with the information from the table. The application is pretty big and using this approach I would need to handle several custom DLLs that would change from time to time. Anyway, your answer got me thinking, so thank you again.

Comment: you're welcome - every case is specific, you know best (you just can't rely on the attributes if someone uses fluent configuration, like I do most of the time - and many things can't be done w/o it - if that's what you mean by attributes). You should still close the question - put your own answer if this isn't fitting enough. Cheers.