# How to get the related tables and key values of a pure relationship record?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have two tables, `Product` and `Category`, which have a pure many to many intersection table, `ProductCategory` (i.e. `ProductCategory` contains only two fields, `ProductID` and `CategoryID`).  EF has modeled this nicely for me, such that `Product` has a `Categories` property and `Category` has a `Products` property.

Now I want to create an audit trail, catching whenever a record is inserted, updated or deleted.  This I have successfully achieved by creating the other half of the partial class `MyEntities` and overriding `SaveChanges()`.  Thus:

```
public override int SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
{
    var inserts = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added).ToList();
    var updates = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified).ToList();
    var deletes = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Deleted).ToList();
    ...
}
```

and for each `ObjectStateEntry` in each of `inserts`, `updates` and `deletes` I can get the entity being modified through the `Entity` property.

This works great for regular tables like `Product` and `Category`, but it bombs out with `ProductCategory`, because the `Entity` property is null.  I've dug around at runtime through the public interface of the `ObjectStateEntry` for the inserted/deleted `ProductCategory`, but can't find anything that will help me identify the key fields and their values.  I want to get:

- The names of the related tables ("Product" and "Category")
- The key values of the related records (values of `ProductID` and `CategoryID`)
- The names of the respective relationships from each table to the intersection ("Categories" and "Products").

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting it right - you should try what we did in here (with the OP's help).
I think that comes pretty close...

[How I can read EF DbContext metadata programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718301/how-i-can-read-ef-dbcontext-metadata-programmatically/15720297#15720297)

specifically, I think...

```
ManyToManyReferences = navigationProperties.Where(np =>
            np.FromEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many &&
            np.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many)
            .Select(np => Extensions.CreateLambdaExpression<TEntity>(np.Name))
            .ToList();
```

---

You may also wanna check this one (and links to other posts I gathered there) for more on the metadata. Or search for `IObjectContextAdapter` or some of the keywords mentioned in here

[Get entity facets and other metadata on runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908554/get-entity-facets-and-other-metadata-on-runtime/15911821#15911821)