# Search all entities with specific property and their entries

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF Code First but my models have NO relationships (PKs - FKs). So I'm trying to find a way to workaround it by using EF6 Reflections in order to avoid an entry deletion that would have relationships (same property name).

- **Lookup over all my context entities** in which has any specific property (FK);
- For every entity found, **check if this entity has any entry**;
- If its true, instead of deleting my entry, set a property "Canceled" as true;
- If its false, keep entity state deleted and save my context changes;

  ```
  public override int SaveChanges()
  {
      foreach (var myEntity in ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditable>())
      {
          if (myEntity.State == EntityState.Deleted)
          {
              ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
              var container = objContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(objContext.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);

              var objectStateEntry = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(myEntity.Entity);
              var entityKeys = objectStateEntry.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues;
              var entity = myEntity;
              var hasAnyFk = false;
              foreach (var entityKey in entityKeys)
              {
                  if (hasAnyFk)
                  {
                      break;
                  }

                  var keyName = entityKey.Key;
                  foreach (var entitySet in container.EntitySets)
                  {
                      hasAnyFk = entitySet.ElementType.Members.Any(es => es.Name == keyName);
                      if (hasAnyFk)
                      {
                          break;
                      }
                  }
              }

              if (hasAnyFk)
              {
                  var deletedProperty = myEntity.OriginalValues.PropertyNames.Where(p => myEntity.Property(p).Name == "Deleted").FirstOrDefault();
                  if (deletedProperty != null)
                  {
                      myEntity.State = EntityState.Modified;
                      myEntity.CurrentValues[deletedProperty] = true;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  ```

  return base.SaveChanges();
  }

Comment: If you are doing code first why not just add the relationships?  This seems like a really strange pattern to choose.  In any case, if your EF classes are in one assembly then I suppose you can scan the assembly for any classes that have the specified property.  You'll want to cache all this information so you aren't scanning each time though.

Comment: @stephen.vakil even adding the relationships, I don't want use on cascade features. I guess it's not strange considering what I want to do - setting property flags instead of literally delete an entry. By setting the relationships won't solve my needing.

Comment: It will help.  One way you have to scan the entire assembly for like-named fields.  The other you can interrogate navigation properties using the built-in EF libraries.  You don't have to enable cascade delete in EF.

Comment: @stephen.vakil indeed, it would help but the app doesn't have the proper relations set and I'm trying to find a way to avoid unexpected deletions. If you would have any better approach, it's going to be very welcome.

Comment: Look at System.Data.Metadata.Edm and samples of querying it, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718301/how-i-can-read-ef-dbcontext-metadata-programmatically

Comment: @stephen.vakil I appreciate your hints. If you could, please have a look my updated post. My only trouble now is about how to make a Select in order to check if the found entity with has any entry.                     `hasAnyFk = entitySet.ElementType.Members.Any(es => es.Name == keyName);
                    if (hasAnyFk)
                    {
                        ?? How to make a dynamic select using this entity ??
                    }`

Comment: After your edit the problem isn't clear anymore. The question now basically is a requirement description and a piece of code that executes it (or doesn't? -- but that's not clear anymore).

Comment: @Gert Arnold, the only thing I did on my edition was to put the whole code together and includes what I asked in my 2 first topics. What you answered was good and I really appreciate it, but please notice your code refers the topics 3 and 4 of my question.

Comment: Sure, that's OK, it's just that it's hard to piece together from your code which part you're still having troubles with. By the way, I think that adding relationships in the class model is a more secure way to control deletions than property name matching. It certainly makes life a lot easier, not only for deletions, but also for querying.

Comment: I have no questions about that putting relationships would help and make this much easier... but I can't do that for now. Its a temporarily workaround. If you have something to suggest I'd appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this is an overload of `SaveChanges`:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == 
                                   System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted).ToList())
    {
        var delPropName = "IsDeleted";
        if (entry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames.Contains(delPropName))
        {
            var delProp = entry.Property(delPropName);
            delProp.CurrentValue = true;
            entry.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Here, `entry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames` is used to check if the property exists in the entity and then its value is set and the entry's state is changed to `Modified`. Note that I loop through `this.ChangeTracker.Entries()` after applying `ToList()`, otherwise the content of the collection changes while looping through it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I had already done this part - checked deleted property and setting true instead of deleting the entry. *My main challenge consists in - Lookup over all my context entities in which has any specific property (FK); - For every entity found, check if this entity has any entry;**. If I have no related entry with same PK, I can delete.

Comment: Any idea how to do this in Efcore? `entry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames` are not available

Comment: @HamzaKhanzada 
entry.Members.Any(f => f.Metadata.Name == "ModifiedOn")